# how to override prepareform in adminhtml folder using magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml

I want to override protected prepareform() method because I want to add new fields so how to override it.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else needs a more complete answer based on '@gajjala sandeep' response:

```
<?php
namespace XXX\XXX\Plugin\Amasty\Label\Block\Adminhtml\Labels\Edit\Tab;

class Conditions
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Amasty\Label\Block\Adminhtml\Labels\Edit\Tab\Conditions $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @return string
     */
    public function aroundGetFormHtml( 
        \Amasty\Label\Block\Adminhtml\Labels\Edit\Tab\Conditions $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) { 
        $form = $subject->getForm();
        if (is_object($form)) { 
            /* Get the fieldset by the parent form's fieldset name */
            $fieldset = $form->getElement('conditions_fieldset');
            $fieldset->addField( 
                'fieldname', 'textarea', 
                ['name' => 'fieldname', 'label' => __('Story B'), 'title' => __('Story B') ]
            ); 

            $model = $this->registry->registry('current_amasty_label');
            $form->addValues($model->getData()); // Using addData() to keep previous data but you can add only your data like: addData(['fieldname' => 'value'])
            $subject->setForm($form); 
        } 
        
        return $proceed(); 
    }
}
```

Declare the plugin on XXX/XXX/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Amasty\Label\Block\Adminhtml\Labels\Edit\Tab\Conditions">
        <plugin name="xxx_xxx_edit_tab_conditions" type="XXX\XXX\Plugin\Amasty\Label\Block\Adminhtml\Labels\Edit\Tab\Conditions" />
    </type>
</config>
```

I hope that helps who come here in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You can override prepareform() function as per the following code:

First, You need to override the di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Vendor\ExtensionName\Block\Adminhtml\ABC\XYZ\Tab\Test" type="OverrideVendor\OverrideExtensionName\Block\Adminhtml\ABC\XYZ\Tab\Test" />
</config>
```

Then you need to a file OverrideVendor\OverrideExtensionName\Block\Adminhtml\ABC\XYZ\Tab\Test.php

```
<?php

namespace OverrideVendor\OverrideExtensionName\Block\Adminhtml\ABC\XYZ\Tab;

class Test extends \Vendor\ExtensionName\Block\Adminhtml\ABC\XYZ\Tab\Test
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {

        $fieldset->addField(
            'add_field', 'text', array(
                'label'    => __('New Fiedl'),
                'name'     => 'add_field',
            )
        );

        $this->setForm($form);
        return $this;

    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any other issues.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, @shankar thanks for the reply I have already completed this task using plugin and thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @gajjalasandeep I'm glad to know that you fixed the issue but can you please also share your answer? Thanks :)

Comment: <type name="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit\Tab\Main"><plugin name="custom" type="Custom\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit\Tab\Main" /></type> ****plugin file ****
public function aroundGetFormHtml( \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit\Tab\Main $subject,\Closure $proceed){ 
$form = $subject->getForm();
if (is_object($form)) {
$fieldset->addField(
'customerscallout',
'textarea',
['name' => 'story',
'label' => __('Story B'),
'title' => __('Story B')
]); $form->setValues($model->getData()); $subject->setForm($form); }
return $proceed();

Comment: Above is the code which I used.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :)

Comment: Always welcome :)

Comment: How can i remove existing field from this" protected function prepareForm()" function